# Is there any why to make FlyCheck learn new html tags?

Tags: flycheck

Is there any why to make FlyCheck learn new html tags? Custom tags? or just html5 tags.

Is there any way to add them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flycheck doesn't know anything about HTML tags; instead, the HTML checker that you use does.

For HTML, the only checker available out of the box is `html-tidy`; thus, you should check whether `html-tidy` supports adding new tags.